# How to restrict entering whitespaces as input to JTextField elements in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm using Java Swing for a Connection GUI. I need to prevent entering whitespaces to the JTextField  elements, especially to password field. I had used isEmpty() or isBlank() to know whether whitespaces are entered. But it didn't worked.
If I enter whitespace it doesn't return true value,as isBlank() should return true if there is whitespace only.

```
String errorMessage = "No Errors"; //Intializing as No errors

private boolean checkValueAndSetErrorMessage(Map<String, String> map) {

    boolean truth = false;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> mapElement : map.entrySet()) {
        if (mapElement.getKey().isEmpty()|| mapElement.getKey().isBlank()) {
            
            errorMessage = String.format("%1$s should not be blank.", mapElement.getValue()); //Changing errorMessage to empty
            truth = false; 
            break;
        } else {
            truth = true;
        }
    }
    return truth;

}
```

Comment: What values do you enter? How do you populate your map? Did you mean only to check your key? Please provide a [mre] of your problem. Also, do you want to restrict the whitespaces directly while entering or only when checking afterwards?

Comment: Seems to me like your usage of the Map is incorrect. The "key" value should be unique, so you can have multiple entries in your Map. So the key should be the description of the text field like "User Id" or "Password". The value will then be the data the user entered for those text fields. As you iterate through the entry set you need to check if the "value" is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
mapElement.getKey().contains(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expression` to test if the key contains any whitespace character.

`Pattern.matches("\\s+", mapElement.getKey())`

For more explanation in the regular expression that I provided,

- `\s+` mean that it will try to match one or more whitespaces characters